# How do I prevent the user from tapping other UIViews (UIBarButtonItem) outside a Popover?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

In my app, I have a Popover which is spawned from a UIBarButtonItem in a UIToolbar. Currently, it is possible to tap the other buttons in the UIToolbar when the Popover is being shown.

How do I still dismiss the Popover when tapping outside it while also not allowing the user to tap on UIViews outside the Popover? Do I just need to disable the views external to the Popover?

```
// prepare Actions Menu
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

actionsVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "actionsViewController") as! ActionsController
actionsVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
actionsVC.graph = graph
actionsVC.viewControllerDelegate = self
```

...

```
@IBAction func openActionsPopover(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        actionsVC.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender
        actionsVC.popoverPresentationController?.passthroughViews?.removeAll()
        present(actionsVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code showing how you create, setup, and display your popover.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there a way NOT to have the popover dismissed when pressing outside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477422/is-there-a-way-not-to-have-the-popover-dismissed-when-pressing-outside-it)

Comment: Added code samples. Attempted the solution given in the other question but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Check [passthroughViews](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller/1622312-passthroughviews) and [modalInPopover](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1619312-ismodalinpopover) property.

Comment: Would this then mean that the other UIViews in the toolbar are somehow being added to passthroughViews by default?

Comment: By default not, an other solution should be to disable the others buttons while your popover is visible using `myBarButtonItem.isEnabled = false`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking but I didn't think it seemed quite right since that would mean setting .isEnabled = false for each UIView. Seems a bit inefficient...

Comment: Yeah you right, read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30944872/2370587 it can help you.

Comment: That didn't work. Setting isModalInPopover to true simply disabled dismissal of the popover by tapping outside it. I still want the popover to be dismissed when tapping outiside of it. I just don't want the user to be able to tap on other buttons when the popover is open.

Comment: Okay so it's possible to trick this using a UITapGestureRecognizer, add this gesture to your main view and for the action simply dismiss the popover.